# Из Intellij Idea в Eclipse

Tags: gwt, ide, java, intellij-idea, eclipse

У меня есть проект веб-приложения, написанного на Java, GWT. Проект писал в Intllij Idea, но в силу некоторых обстоятельств его необходимо перенести в Eclipse. Попробовал переложить код и настроить Run Config'и, не вышло. Проект собирается, но сервер выдает ошибку

```
HTTP ERROR: 503
SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
RequestURI=/index.html
```

Подскажите правильно перенести код, затратив по минимуму усилий.

Answer (score 4):

Можно сделать maven-проект, он может открываться и в eclipse и в idea, при наличии соответствующих плагинов.

Comment: Спасибо, в следующий раз буду использовать maven, но как поступить в данном случае (имеется большой проект в Intellij Idea)?

Comment: В GWT из командной строки можно создать проект eclipse, имя основного класса в GWT подаётся в качестве параметра. Такой проект будет запускаться, можно просто переложить код. Если модулей в idea было несколько, придётся создать соответствующие несколько javaEE проекты и настроить между ними зависимости, причём не через build path, есть отдельно javaEE dependencies. Возможно вы прописали их только в build path.

Comment: Это не выход, это тоже самое, что просто создать проект в эклипсе и туда копировать. У меня на руках не три строчки кода.

Comment: Тогда надо разбираться конкретно, где падает GWT. Было бы здорово если бы можно было отконвертировать проект. Именно из-за таких случаев лучше использовать maven и gradle.